# How to download webpage into a git repo with separate html, css, and js

Tags: html, download

Basically I want to download a website and customize it. I am aware of "save as" with google, but that puts it all under one file which I do not know how to parse out the css and js.

Comment: have you find something useful here ?

Answer (score 0):

To copy "www.example.com", use

```
$ wget --recursive --page-requisites --no-parent https://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score -1):

Httrack is a software that can be use for dowload a website with many file for local usage.
But why just ask a dev to recreate the design that you like and personalise for yourself ?
sorry for sad english ^^